# PySerial: How to send Ctrl-C command on the serial line

Tags: python, serial-port, copy-paste, pyserial

I'm automating a configuration process for an embedded board.  To enter the setup screen I need to send "Ctrl-C" command.

This is **NOT** to interrupt a process I'm running locally, **KeyboardInterrupt** will **not work**.  I need to send a value that will be interpreted by the bootloader as Ctrl-C.

What is the value I need to send?

Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IIRC, Ctrl-C is `etx`.  Thus send `\x03`.

Comment: See also, the wikipedia pages on [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [ETX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character).

Answer (score 10):

You should send a character with the ASCII code 3:

```
serial.write('\x03')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\x03
```

Which means 'end of text' or 'break' is what Ctrl+C sends.

Comment: any idea how to use it in a python3 script?

Answer (score 4):

Python doesn't take the ASCII code as a string, it needs to be encoded as bytes. So just add **b** before the code.

```
serial.write(b'\x03')
```

I've used here and saved and saved my life a couple times.