# Send ^D over Serial with Python

Tags: pyserial

I have a script that configures a Juniper router to my companies specifications. Nothing overly fancy it just follows the procedures they gave me. And reads in whatever file configuration is in a specified folder. Anyhow, the very last step in the procedure is to his Ctrl + D for end of transmission. Strangely, this problem seems to be unique to me, ^C and ^V seem to be common characters, but not ^D. I have tried /EOT.  Does anyone know how this simple script would go about sending ^D? The code hangs on /EOT, which is why I'm guessing that I'm not expressing that character right.

```
   ser.write ('root\r\n') 
    time.sleep(5)
    ser.write ('cli\r\n')
    ser.write('configure\r\n')  
    ser.write('top\r\n')
    ser.write('load set terminal\r\n')
    file = open('REDACTED', 'r+')
    text = file.read()
    ser.write(text + '/r')
    ser.write('\n')
    ser.write('\EOT')
    ser.write('commit and-quit\r\n')
```

`

Answer (score 2):

The [escape sequence](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html) '\EOT' does not exist.

In order to send ASCII code 0x04 (EOT) use following command:

```
ser.write( b'\x04' );   # send ^D (EOT)
```

See also [PySerial: How to send Ctrl-C command on the serial line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018139/pyserial-how-to-send-ctrl-c-command-on-the-serial-line)