# How to send Linux interrupt signal? C#

Tags: c#, linux, terminal, serial-port

I have a small project that provides communication through the serial port on the C# and the serial port device runs Linux. A process can normally terminated by CTRL+C on Terminal, Tera Term or PuTTY... How can I provide this fucntion?

For example, I send this command to serial port device "ping 127.0.0.1" and the device start to pinging. So when I want to stop this process, I have to send a signal for this via CTRL+C. How can I do this?

Comment: [coreutils | kill.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/kill.c) source code. Also see [`kill(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1@@coreutils.html) man page, which explains how to use the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySerial: How to send Ctrl-C command on the serial line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018139/pyserial-how-to-send-ctrl-c-command-on-the-serial-line)